# How to stop a Hive metastore service?

Tags: hive

How do I stop a Hive metastore service that I started using:

```
hive --service metastore
```

without the kill command?

Comment: without the kill command , restarting hive server is the only option i guess.

Answer (score 3):

If u r running it in pseudo cluster .I.e single node cluster u can kill the metastore by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in the same terminal.

Usually in multinode cluster they will fire the services with `nohup` so that it will run in background. U can check the running services and kill it. Try using the below commands.

`ps aux | grep {process-name}` - this will give you the process id.

`kill -9 <process_id>` - this will kill the process

Answer (score 0):

Hive *should* have been installed with a service script, so that it can be started/shutdown gracefully in the correct order (i.e., after networking is started, database running, etc), so it's likely you can do: `sudo service hiveserver2 stop` and `sudo service hive-metastore stop` (e.g., [cloudera distro](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_start.html))

As as backup, you can "kill" the parent process using `kill {PID}` (but **not** `kill -9 {PID}`).

Note: never send `sigkill` (aka `-9`) signal to any process except as a very last resort. Instead, send the `sigterm` / `sigint` (same as ctrl-c, aka "interrupt") signal first, which is what `kill` sends by default, e.g, `ps -ef | egrep -i 'hive'`, see what the main process is (the parent of other related processes), and terminate the process via `kill {PID}` e.g., `kill 12345`. The `sigint` signal can be caught by the running process and still do a graceful shutdown/clean-up. The `sigkill` can't be caught, and will almost certainly leave your system in an uncertain state and maybe (or maybe not) it'll have to recover somehow at next startup.

Answer (score 0):

I use hive in an AWS cluster and `sudo stop hive-hcatalog-server` works.